# ¿Cómo gestionar las etiquetas <br> cuando se quiere extraer texto de un código html con BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

Tengo éste trozo de código html:

```
<tr class="row-2 even">
<td class="column-1">Dirección Postal</td><td class="column-2">Escuela 
Superior de Ingeniería<br />
<br />
Avenida de la Universidad de Cádiz, nº 10<br />
<br />
11519 - Puerto Real, Cádiz</td>
</tr>
```

Estoy usando Python y concretamente Beautifulsoup, y mi intención es extraer todo el texto de modo que quede formateado de este modo:

> Dirección Postal: Escuela Superior de Ingeniería
>
> Avenida de la Universidad de Cádiz, nº 10
>
> 11519 - Puerto Real, Cádiz

Estoy usando éste trozo de código en Python:

```
Sopa = BeautifulSoup(Ruta_html, "html.parser")

Sopa_td1 = Sopa.select('td[class="column-1"]')
Sopa_td2 = Sopa.select('td[class="column-2"]')

for i in range(len(Sopa_td1)): #Sopa_td1 y Sopa_td2 tienen el mismo número de elementos.
    Sopa_td1_Limpio = Sopa_td1[i].get_text()
    Sopa_td2_Limpio = Sopa_td2[i].get_text()
```

La parte problemática se corresponde con una de las iteraciones de la segunda columna en este trozo de código:

```
Sopa_td2_Limpio = Sopa_td2[i].get_text()
```

cuyo resultado es:

> Escuela Superior de Ingeniería\n', '\n', 'Avenida de la Universidad de Cádiz, nº 10\n', '\n', '11519 - Puerto Real, Cádiz

Además estoy usando Django para mostrar ésta información en un servidor local y en el template correspondiente he escrito este trozo que debería cambiar los '\n' por saltos de línea (br):

```
<h3>{{ salida|linebreaksbr }}</h3>
```

y esta es la salida final:

[image: Salida]

Sospecho que son esas comillas simples las culpables de que no se creen los saltos de línea.

¿Habría alguna alternativa u opción particular de "get_text", o algún truco para gestionar esas etiquetas br?

Mi versión de Python es: 3.4.3
y mi versión de Django es: 1.9.7

**Actualización:**

Efectivamente, siguiendo el consejo de los comentarios, probé a insertar el código html directamente entre triples comillas y funcionó perfectamente.

El problema estaba en el origen de los datos, ya que "Ruta_html" que he escrito para simplificar, viene de una transformación explicita de una lista a una cadena de texto usando "str".

Por lo tanto, el trozo de código html de origen no es exactamente el descrito en este post, sino que está "contaminado" con diversos caracteres: (comillas simples, corchetes, comas, tabulaciones y saltos de línea)

Más concretamente, el origen es una lista obtenida de:

```
 Tit_Datos_Tot = Soup(Directiva).select('tr[class^="row"]')
```

Donde "Soup" es una función que recibe una clave que corresponde a una URL, en este caso: "http://esingenieria.uca.es/centro/datos-del-centro/equipo-directivo/" y devuelve un objeto bs4 del que selecciono una tabla de etiqueta "tr" cuyo nombre de la clase comienza por "row".

Como se puede ver en la página y en el código fuente, esta tabla contiene al director, subdirectores... Entonces según lo que busque el usuario, delimito esa tabla con índices:

```
Tabla_director = Tit_Datos_Tot[ind_tot_ini:ind_tot_fin]
```

He pensado hacerlo de este modo porque toda la información del director está primero entre etiquetas "th" y luego entre varias "td". Entonces el índice inicial "ind_tot_ini" lo obtengo del lugar donde se encuentra la clave entre etiquetas "th" y el índice final "ind_tot_fin" lo obtengo de donde se encuentra la próxima etiqueta "th".

Y así es como he llegado hasta la tabla inicial origen del problema, por lo tanto, "Ruta_html" del inicio del post sería:

```
Ruta_html = str(Tabla_director)
```

He seleccionado el trozo problemático y lo he formateado de  este modo:

```
Tit_format = re.sub('\', \'', '', str(Tit_Datos_Tot[ind_tot_ini:ind_tot_fin][0]))
Tit_format = Tit_format.replace('\\t', '')
Tit_format = Tit_format.replace('<br/>', '<br />')
print ('TIT_FORMAT = ', Tit_format)
```

que ahora queda así:

[image: Formateado]

Pero desgraciadamente después de modificar esta línea:

```
Sopa = BeautifulSoup(Tit_format, "html.parser")
```

el resultado es este:

[image: Resultado]

y si elimino los saltos de línea y dejo las etiquetas br, el resultado es el mismo pero sin los "\n"

¿Por qué se reconocen los saltos de línea insertados por teclado, pero su representación "\n" no? ¿Cómo los represento entonces en una cadena de texto?

Tal como me ha pedido @FJSevilla, he añadido más información, que espero que sirva más para hacer entender el problema que para alargar demasiado la pregunta y volveros locos.

Comment: ¿Si aplicas el filtro `<h3>{{salida|linebreaks}}<h3>` en su lugar obtienes el mismo resultado?

Comment: De donde salen esas comas? a mi con python 2.7 el get_text me da u'Escuela \nSuperior de Ingenier\xeda\n\nAvenida de la Universidad de C\xe1diz, n\xba 10\n\n11519 - Puerto Real, C\xe1diz' y Django 1.10 lo imprime bien con el filtro linebreaksbr

Comment: Si FJSevilla, lo acabo de probar y obtengo el mismo resultado. Txema, no lo sé, supongo que en mi versión get_text() actúa de esa manera con los br... ¿Tendrá algo que ver la codificación?

Comment: Mi type(Sopa_td2_Limpio) es <type 'unicode'>, el tuyo parece una lista de líneas.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar en Python 3 y el resultado es el mismo que @Txema muestra, solo que la salida es de tipo `str` (`unicode` de Python2.x) como cabe esperar en Python3.x: 'Escuela \nSuperior de Ingeniería\n\nAvenida de la Universidad de Cádiz, nº 10\n\n11519 - Puerto Real, Cádiz'. Algo se nos escapa, como cdice Txema lo tuyo parece un iterable, lista o tupla de cadenas. Prueba a pasar la lista a una cadena : `Sopa_td2_Limpio = ''.join(Sopa_td2_Limpio)`

Comment: Si, da la impresión que el problema se encuentra en algún pequeño detalle. Yo he comprobado el tipo de  `Sopa_td2_Limpio ` y es "<class str>", aún así he probado a usar  `Sopa_td2_Limpio = ''.join(Sopa_td2_Limpio) ` pero sin resultado. Sigo investigando a ver.

Comment: Por descartar cosas, ¿Como obtienes y que estructura tiene `Ruta_html`?, ¿si metes el fragmento html que muestras estre comillas triples: `Ruta_html='''pega_tu_codigo_html'''` y ejecutas las lineas para parsearlo obtienes la misma salida? El error debe andar por los datos de origen porque nosotros no podemos reproducir tu salida, ejecutando tu código con ese fragmento se obtiene: `'Escuela \nSuperior de Ingeniería\n\nAvenida de la Universidad de Cádiz, nº 10\n\n11519 - Puerto Real, Cádiz'`

Comment: Tienes razón, he probado meter el trozo de código directamente con comillas triples y efectivamente funciona, así que el problema viene de los datos de origen. Como dijo Txema, esas comas vienen de otra parte, parecían una lista de líneas y de hecho es una lista convertida a string explícitamente con str. Intento resolverlo y escribo la respuesta. ¡Gracias a los dos!

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta, ya que aunque he descubierto de donde viene el problema, no he conseguido arreglarlo del todo. Por favor, échenle un vistazo.

Comment: Te aconsejaria que de ser posible postearas la lista original sin modificar nada o al menos una parte de ella pero en formato lista, así podemos hacernos una idea desde donde partes. Por otro lado ¿lo que muestras en la captura, TIT_FORMAT que es o de que tipo es? Si fuera un string no habria ningún problema, la salida sería la esperada. Me da la sensación de que te estás complicando en exceso pero para poder ayudar el problema debe ser reproducible con **solo** lo que aportas en la pregunta porque no disponemos de la información que tu dispones. Intenta no usar capturas, pega el código.

Comment: De acuerdo, ya está editado el post. Espero haber añadido las piezas que faltaban al puzzle. No quería escribir demasiado texto y código para no hacer demasiada larga la pregunta y "liar más que aclarar", pero parece que me he quedado demasiado corto :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto se complica por momentos, sigo sin poder reproducir tu problema... :(. Intentando simularlo con lo que explicas he llegado al siguiente código:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


html = requests.get("http://esingenieria.uca.es/centro/datos-del-centro/equipo-directivo/") 
Tit_Datos_Tot = BeautifulSoup(html.text,"html.parser").select('tr[class^="row"]')

Tit_format = str(Tit_Datos_Tot[1:3][0])
Sopa = BeautifulSoup(Tit_format, "html.parser")
Sopa_td1 = Sopa.select('td[class="column-1"]')
Sopa_td2 = Sopa.select('td[class="column-2"]')

Sopa_td1_Limpio=None
Sopa_td2_Limpio=None
for i in range(len(Sopa_td1)): #Sopa_td1 y Sopa_td2 tienen el mismo número de elementos.
    Sopa_td1_Limpio = Sopa_td1[i].get_text()
    Sopa_td2_Limpio = Sopa_td2[i].get_text()

print(Sopa_td2_Limpio)
```

Los indices que he usado para seleccionar la porción de tu ejemplo son `ind_tot_ini = 1` e `ind_tot_fin = 3`. He omitido todos los procedimientos de reemplazo de caracteres (en mi caso el resultado es el mismo con o sin esas lineas). Pues bién la salida es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cadena que contiene `Sopa_td2_Limpio` es la siguiente:

> 'Escuela Superior de Ingeniería \n\nAvenida de la Universidad de Cádiz, nº 10\n\n11519 - Puerto Real, Cádiz'

Algo hacemos diferente, esta claro. Uso [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) para obtener el texto de la url pero esto es indiferente. A ver si a partir de esto podemos avanzar y dar con el problema. Mira a ver que diferencias encuentras (si es que no estoy muy perdido yo y alejado de lo que intentas hacer).

**EDICIÓN:**

Según lo sugerido en un comentario no se obtine el html desde la web directamente sino desde un archivo local (`index.html`). El archivo se puede abrir con open sin problemas a no ser que se use el método `readlines()` para obtener los datos. El problema es que `readlines` retorna una **lista** con cada línea del documento. Esto es lo que en principio causaba todo el problema.

No debes usar `readlines` sino `read`que retorna un objeto `str` o `bytes` dependiendo del modo de lectura y que contiene el texto en crudo tal y como lo obtienes de la url. No obstante el constructor de la clase `BeautifulSoup` acepta un objeto `_io.BufferedReader` (lo que retorna `open` en Python 3.x) directamente como argumento de entrada como puedes ver en la [documentación](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Tit_Datos_Tot = BeautifulSoup(open("index.html", 'rb'),"html.parser").select('tr[class^="row"]')
Tit_format = str(Tit_Datos_Tot[1:3][0])
Sopa = BeautifulSoup(Tit_format, "html.parser")
Sopa_td1 = Sopa.select('td[class="column-1"]')
Sopa_td2 = Sopa.select('td[class="column-2"]')

Sopa_td1_Limpio=None
Sopa_td2_Limpio=None
for i in range(len(Sopa_td1)): #Sopa_td1 y Sopa_td2 tienen el mismo número de elementos.
    Sopa_td1_Limpio = Sopa_td1[i].get_text()
    Sopa_td2_Limpio = Sopa_td2[i].get_text()

print(Sopa_td2_Limpio)
```

Me he descargado la web y he aplicado el código sobre `index.html` situado en `\esingenieria.uca.es\centro\datos-del-centro\equipo-directivo\index.html` dentro del directorio creado por HTTrack y la salida correcta, identica a la anterior que pongo en la respuesta.

Comment: He probado tu código y obtengo el resultado correcto, tal como me muestras, lo que me ha hecho pensar en un detalle que antes creía irrelevante: El código fuente no lo he extraido directamente de la url que he escrito, sino que me he descargado la página con "HTTrack" y he obtenido el texto del archivo "index.html" con `f = open (Ruta_html, "r", encoding='utf8')` `Fcontenido = f.readlines()` y `Tit_Datos_Tot = BeautifulSoup(str(Fcontenido),"html.parser").select('tr[class^="row"]')` y  de este modo obtengo el resultado erroneo original con sus comas, comillas y otros caracteres indeseables.

Comment: El caso es que he comparado detalladamente el trozo de código fuente directamente de la página con el del archivo html y son exactamente iguales. Ya lo había comparado con otras páginas, cada archivo html con la correspondiente y no había visto diferencia, y por este motivo no lo consideré relevante. Sospecho entonces que el problema debe de estar en la forma de obtener el texto.  ¿Quizá debo usar una alternativa a "open"? ¿Tendrá algo que ver la codificación? ¡Estamos estrechando el cerco!

Comment: @Miguelw open no debe ser el problema a no ser que uses  `readlines` retorna una lista y cada elemento es una linea con su `\n` correspondiente. He editado la pregunta a ver si por fin llegamos a algo :).

Comment: ¡Ese era el problema! ¡readlines()! He usado como parámetro de BeautifulSoup directamente la apertura del archivo y ha ido todo como la seda. Ahora me queda solo una duda: ¿Como puedo pasarte otros 50 de reputación? Es más, ¿Como puedo pedir un préstamo de reputación para pasarte otros 200? :D Bromas aparte, perdona por los dolores de cabeza y muchísimas gracias :) Un saludo.

Comment: Hahaha... de nada hombre, no ha sido para tanto, la verdad es que era mas la intriga de saber que leches pasaba porque no había manera de reproducir el problema, el error era simple lo malo era que estaba al principio de todo XD. Saludos.